# Criteria Querying question

Tags: hibernate, criteria

how to select particular field using Criteria ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Projections, see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection